# Problema al leer una direccion dado por el usuario

Tags: c

Estoy desarollando un programa que permita leer los datos de un archivo y asignarselos a un struct, sin embargo como no conozco el nombre del archivo opte por pedirselo al usuario.
mi Struct es este:

```
struct puntos
{
      int idPunto;
      float valorX;
      float valorY;
      float Modulo;
      float Angulo;

};
```

Hice este codigo:

```
     char dir[100];
     char conta[100];
     struct puntos *punto;
     FILE *arch;
     int numeroPuntos;

printf("Ingresa la direccion / nombre (sin el .txt) del archivo, en caso de que no sepas la direccion.\nCopia el archivo en la misma carpeta del programa e indica el nombre (sin el .txt) del archivo:\n");
    scanf("%s",&dir);
    strcat(dir,".txt");
    printf("%s\n",dir);
    arch = fopen(dir,"r");

    if(arch == NULL){
    printf("Error, no se ha podido abrir el archivo\n");
    fflush(stdin);
    goto random;
    }
    else{

    printf("Abriendo el archivo");

    while( fgets(conta,100, (FILE *) arch ))
    {
        numeroPuntos++; 
    }
    printf("%d", numeroPuntos);

    rewind(arch);
    punto=(struct puntos*)realloc(punto,sizeof(struct puntos)*numeroPuntos);

    if(punto != NULL){
        while(!feof(arch)){
            for(int i=0;i<numeroPuntos;i++){
                    rewind(arch);
                    fscanf(arch,"%d %f %f %f %f",&punto[i].idPunto,&punto[i].valorX,&punto[i].valorY,&punto[i].Modulo,&punto[i].Angulo);
                    printf("%d %f %f %f %f\n",punto[i].idPunto,punto[i].valorX,punto[i].valorY,punto[i].Modulo,punto[i].Angulo);
                }
            }
        }
    fclose(arch);
    }
```

El problema que he tenido es que al momento de introducir una direccion valida, el programa se cicla. Puse varios mensajes de error para ayudarme, pero el unico mensaje que obtengo de consola es ***Segmentation Fault (core aborted)***

Comment: He visto el código por *encima*, por lo que veo, nunca inicializas el puntero `punto`. Practicamente le estás basando al primer parámetro de la función `realloc` *basura*. Para que `realloc` se comporte como `malloc`, el puntero `punto` debe ser inicializado a `NULL`. En tu caso, mas bien podrías usar directamente la función `malloc`.

Comment: @MrDave1999 Ya también lo he intentado con malloc, pero me aparece el mismo error, de todos modos por el comportamiento que muestra, creo que hay un error en el fopen porque es más o menos aho donde salta el error

Answer (score 0):

Efectivamente como dijo @MrDave1999 cambie el realloc por malloc pero el problema surgio por el rewind dentro del ciclo for, solo era cosa de borrarlo y ya funciona perfectamente